# How to send a message from background *only* to popup without a tabId

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

In a Firefox/Chrome WebExtension, when you send a message from the background script to the popup, you can't use a tabId because the popup doesn't have one.
So you have to use:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(data)
```

but this message is received by all tabs also.
I want to send a message *only* to the popup. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Technically, this is only received by *extension's pages.* Normal tabs won't receive them, and to send messages to content scripts you need `tabs.sendMessage`.

That said, you can use `extension.getViews` to get the popup's `window` object and call something there directly.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/extension/getViews

```
var windows = chrome.extension.getViews({type: "popup"});
if (windows.length) {
  windows[0].something();
}
```